# Laravel and MySQL not playing well in case of DateTime

Tags: laravel

I created a webapp using Laravel and SQLite,everything was going great.Now,I want to use MySQL as database but now I am unable to add data to my tables.

This is the field from my migration:

```
$table->dateTime('last_updated')->nullable();
```

and this is how I am populating the field using laravel:

```
$client->last_updated = time();
```

But it is giving me error like:

```
Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '1402140378' for column 'last_updated' at row 1 (SQL: update `clients` set `last_updated` = 1402140378 where `id` = 1)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`$table->dateTime`](http://laravel.com/docs/schema#adding-columns) creates an [`DATETIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) column in your database that expects a value of `YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss`. What you're inserting is a unix timestamp.

You can either use [`Carbon`](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) (requires `use Carbon\Carbon` at the top of your file),

```
$client->last_updated = Carbon::now()
```

[`date(...)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php),

```
$client->last_updated = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

or PHP's [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class to insert the current datetime to the database..